# Tapestry 5 redirect mixed case URL to lowercase

Tags: java, redirect, seo, tapestry

URLs in Tapestry 5 are case-insensitive, meaning you can type `http://www.mYsItE.com/iNDEX` and it will load  `http://www.mysite.com/index`. The address bar will display the domain name in lower-case but preserve the capitalization you used for pages (e.g. the above example will appear as `http://www.mysite.com/iNDEX` in the address bar after the page loads)

For SEO purposes we are looking to have our website 301 redirect any mixed-case URL to all-lowercase - converting the entire URL to lowercase, not just the domain. Is there a way to configure Tap5 to 301-redirect mixed-case URLs to lowercase?

(I hope this question isn't too broad. Forgive me if so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [contribute](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html) a [HttpServletRequestFilter](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/HttpServletRequestFilter.html) to the [HttpServletRequestHandler](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/HttpServletRequestHandler.html) or you could contribute a [RequestFilter](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/RequestFilter.html) to the [RequestHandler](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/RequestHandler.html). The preferred approach is a RequestFilter.

Make sure you order your filter contribution `before:*` so that it executes before the rest of the [request processing](http://tapestry.apache.org/request-processing.html)

eg MyAppModule.java

```
public static void contributeRequestHandler(OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> config) {
   config.addInstance(MyRequestFilter.class, "before:*");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding to you sooner; I chose to receive email notifications for this question, but apparently those notifications aren't going out, so I didn't realize I had received an answer. Thank you, I'll try that out.